# JSF 2 ajax example not working

Tags: java

started with this example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_ajax.htm

eclipse does not like the .xhtml file provided with it, i used this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <h:head>
      <title>JSF tutorial</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <h2>Ajax Example</h2>
          <h:form>
          <h:inputText id="inputName" value="#{userData.name}"></h:inputText>
           <h:commandButton value="Show Message">
             <f:ajax execute="inputName" render="outputMessage" />
          </h:commandButton>
          <h2><h:outputText id="outputMessage"
             value="#{userData.welcomeMessage !=null ?
                userData.welcomeMessage : ''}"
             /></h2>
          </h:form>
       </h:body>
    </html>
```

apparently the doctype wasnt right.

and of course the UserData from the tutorial. when running the project on tomcat 9 i can see the title and h2 heading, but no button or input field.

why is that?

i actually asked this question on serverfault, but since it was closed there i reposted it here. i hope that is ok.

somebody answered on serverfault and after that i did change my pom.xml to this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ajax-2</groupId>
  <artifactId>ajax-2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

and did run "maven clean install" on the command line in the project directory.
after downloading a lot of smaller files it said if finished.
yet the webpage does not change, theres nothing on it besides the title and one heading.

this is my web.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ajax-2</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so what did i miss to get this simple example running?

Comment: So you followed every step in the tutorial including environment setp, and "Fist Application?"

Comment: i did that, at leat now. environment setup was easy. but now the first maven command:  
    mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test   -DartifactId=helloworld  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp

Comment: fails with:  
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-   archetype-plugin:2.4:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:create for parameter #: Cannot create instance of interface org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository: org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository.<init>() -> [Help

Comment: i see two possibilities here, the tutorials are not that good (to many errors) or second: the overall structure of a jsf application is just not user friendly....seems like a little monster to me.

and the stackoverflow comment just ignores my whitespaces...great.

Answer (score 0):

i did never find out what was wrong with this, but for readers of this post the ajaxguessnumber example from the java ee tutorials runs without a hitch in netbeans.

Also this tutorial:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html#overview

is great for getting into jsf2 / websockets.